# Problems with vue.config.js, does not redirect correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When I access the backend, it redirects to the api and because the api does not have such a page, it returns 404 (Not found). Here is vue.config.js

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/backend': {
        target: 'https://address1',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { '^/backend': '/api' },
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
      '^/api': {
        target: 'https://address2',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/api' },
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: It's unknown what you do on your side to observe this. Do you run a devserver or build an app? Which request is done to remote server? This needs to be logged and debugged

Comment: I'm creating an application, sending a GET request to a remote server, but when I send a GET request to address1, my requests are sent to address2. I don’t know if it will help or not, but address1/api/v1/... and addess2/api/v1/... are two remote servers

Comment: Can you clarify, is what you described in the comment the expected or actual behaviour?

Comment: this is expected behavior

Comment: The question is unspecific, ssee https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please, provide info on the requests. It's unclear to which hosts you do requests. The problem could be a misunderstanding how devserver proxies work. Or the config. If you want localhost:1234/backend/... to proxy a request to address1/api/... then it likely should be `target: 'https://address1/api`, no pathRewrite